# Check if a key is available in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary

I have a dictionary with objects as keys. How can I check if specific object is available in the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var b:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

if(b[key] != null) {

}
```

Comment: What if I have explicitly set the b[key] = null; In this case the key is available in the dictionary, but it has value null?

Answer (score 19):

hasOwnProperty won't work if the key is an object rather than a string.

checking that the value is null won't work if the key is in the dictionary, but with a null value.

The 'in' operator seems to work all the time.

```
var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var a:Object = new Object();
d[a] = 'foo';
var b:Object = new Object();
d[b] = null;
var c:Object = new Object();
trace(a in d);
trace(b in d);
trace(c in d);
```

Returns

```
true
true
false
```

I believe this is a 'more correct' answer than the one posted above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use array syntax and see if the value is null,

```
assertTrue(myDict["key"] == null)
```

If nulls are allowed values, use the [hasOwnProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#hasOwnProperty%28%29) method.

```
assertTrue(myDict.hasOwnProperty("key")==true)
```

Adobe, why don't you have a keyExists() function?

Comment: hasOwnProperty works when the key is a string but does not work if they key is an object

Answer (score 4):

The most proper way is to compare the returned value with `undefined`:

```
if (dict["key"] !== undefined)
{
    // do code when value does exist
}
```

as a key with a `null` associated value could exist in a dictionary.

[Here](http://brnka.com/article/13-as3-how-to-check-if-a-value-of-a-given-key-exists-in-dictionary) is a good article that explains the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to check for existing keys:

```
if ('key' in dict)
{
    // do something
}
```

It works with object keys as well:

```
if (obj in dict)
{
    // do something
}
```

Note that "obj" must be an existing object (defined or not) or it won't compile.